# how to take the dual problem of a problem that has a sum in it?

Tags: optimization, computer-science, linear-programming

I'm learning about dual problems and was trying to get to an understanding of how to take the dual of a problem that has a sum in it.

For example if we try to optimize the sum of all values while keeping their cost bellow a certain value (knapsack)

```
max sum i=1...n(sixi)
where
sum i=1...n(pixi)<=p 
x>0
```

how would I go about taking the dual of such a problem (doesn't have to be this problem this is only the example)?

I know that standard way for getting a dual problem is to try and get it in the following formula:

```
max cx
where Ax <b 
 x>0
```

corresponds to

```
min b^T y 
where
 A^T > c^T
y >0
```

But how does this work when there is a sum involved? I'm sorry if I'm screwing this up I'm mainly used towards thinking in terms of algorithms and procedures rather then pure mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A summation typically leads to an indexed equation in the dual. Let me try with your example:

Primal problem:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & \sum_i s_i x_i \\
     & \sum_i p_i x_i \le P \perp y\\
     & x_i \ge 0
\end{array}
$$

This is a knapsack problem: one constraint. So we have one dual variable $y$. The notation $\perp$ can be read as "with dual...". In the dual problem we will have as many equations as there are variables in the primal.

Dual problem:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
 \min & Py \\
      & p_i y \ge s_i \perp x_i & \forall i \\
      & y \ge 0
\end{array}
$$